# D3.js: accessing a function's output

Tags: javascript, d3.js, callback

As a novice in Javascript, I'm having trouble understanding how to access the following function's output:

```
function dimensionLabels(d) {
  return __.dimensions[d].title ? __.dimensions[d].title : d;  // dimension display names
}
```

What I do understand is that when it is passed as a callback function in .text, it successfully returns some text which displays in the browser (e.g. "Header [n°1]"):

```
    .append("svg:text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', -10)
      .attr('class', "label")

      .append('svg:tspan')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('dy', 0)
      .text(dimensionLabels)
```

So I'm assuming dimensionLabels returns some string, as if I replace .text(dimensionLabels) with .text("myString"), the original text ("Header [n°1]") is successfully replaced with "myString".

However, what I'd need to do is access the text from dimensionLabels and process it e.g. using:

```
.text(dimensionLabels.split('[', 2))
```

But this produces the following error:

> TypeError: dimensionLabels.split is not a function

Could someone kindly describe how the function above works, and what I should do to access its output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text` takes a function as a parameter and then calls it internally passing it a `d` (datum) argument.  So, since `.text` wants a function just create your own anonymous one and wrapper the call to `dimensionLabels`:

```
.text(function(d){
  var string = dimensionLabels(d);
  return string.split('[', 2);
})
```

**Response to Comments**

The `d3` `.text` method can take either a string **or** a function that returns a string.  If you give it a string it sets the text to that string.  If you give it a function, that function **is not** invoked immediately.  Instead, under the hood, `d3` invokes it later.  When it does, it passes in the `d` argument and this `d` argument is the datum bound to that piece of the DOM.  (At some point your code is data-binding with a `.data` call).

You get an error when you call `dimensionLabels("myString")` because of this line:

```
__.dimensions[d].title
```

You have some object named `__` which has a property of `dimensions`.  The property is either an array or object which can be indexed into (I don't know because you have provided enough code for me to sure):

```
__.dimensions["myString"]
```

returns *undefined*.  And *undefined* will never have a property named `title`.  And BAM, you get your error.

Comment: Thank you! This indeed worked great, but I'm still not sure I grasp the underlying logic. How does the script _know_ what *d* is? Running dimensionLabels(d) within the anonymous function you propose works fine, but if I ran it outside (e.g. .text(dimensionLabels(d)), it would of course not work, though I feel d isn't pointing to anything in both cases. Also, if I run .text(dimensionLabels("myString")), shouldn't I get "myString", based on the conditional return of the function (_return d if false_)? Instead, i get another error: *TypeError: __.dimensions[d] is undefined*..

Comment: @sc28, see my response to your questions above.

Answer (score 1):

`dimensionLabels` looks like it is a function, not a string, that takes a string as an argument.

Then, it looks like it is looking at the `__` object for a property, that is an array, called `dimensions`, and then looking for an index `[d]`, which may have a property `title` to use as its text. If not, then it just returns the argument that you gave it `d`.

So, if you are trying to use it, you need to pass it a string to return either the result of `__.dimensions[d].title`, or if it is not found, then just the string, perhaps like this `dimensionsLabels("someText")`. Then, you will get a string back to you and you can call `.split()` on the result, or on the whole thing: `dimensionsLabels("someText").split('[', 2)`

The way you are doing it is calling `.split()` on a function, which, for the most part I believe, `.split()` is for strings.

Comment: Thanks, spelling out the workflow was quite helpful. However, I'm still not sure I get the function's underlying mechanism, as I wrote in my comment to @Mark's response. In particular, passing a string in the function doesn't return it, although as you wrote, it _should_ return the given argument d if no "title" property is found.